# Help with a problem involving limit theorems

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Here's a problem I am stuck on. The problem goes as follows:

Suppose the distribution of scores of a test has mean 100 and standard deviation 16. Calculate an upper bound for the probability $P\{X>148\space or \space X<52\}$.

So here is my progress

By the addivity axiom, $P\{X>148\space or \space X<52\}=P\{X>148\}+P\{X<52\}$.
Can I use Chebyshev's Inequality on both probabilities or do I use the one-sided Chebyshev Inequality? Or do I use the corollary from the one-sided chebyshev inequality (stated below)?

$P\{X\ge \mu+a\} \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$ (1)

$P\{X\le \mu-a\} \le \frac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$ (2)

Being that the problem states $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $a$, I believe I should use the corollary to get an upper bound.

Comment: Seems fine. Where is the question? This is an upper bound, but one is an upper bound as well;)

Comment: Can I use the first portion of the corollary for $P\{X>148\}$ and the second portion for $P\{X<52\}?

Comment: Sure the measure is continuous $P(X >c )= P(X \geq C)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the interval is symmetric about the mean, use the Chebyshev Inequality in the version
$$\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge k\sigma)\le \frac{1}{k^2}.$$
The only issue is that we should choose for $k$. Since $148$ and $52$ are both $3$ standard deviation units from the mean, we can take $k=3$, and conclude that $\frac{1}{9}$ is an upper bound for our probability.

But since here the random variable (test score) is probably integer valued, we really want the probability that $x\ge 149$ or $x\le 51$. That would give $k=\frac{49}{16}$, and lead to a somewhat improved upper bound of roughly $0.1067$.

**Remark:** Because $\frac{48}{16}$ is the "nice" number $3$, you are probably intended to treat the grade as if it had continuous distribution, and obtain the bound $\frac{1}{9}$.

Comment: How did you figure that 148 and 52 are 3 standard deviations  from each other?

Comment: Not from each other, but from the mean. The problem said that the mean of the test is $100$. each of $148$ and $52$ is at distance $48$ from $100$.

Comment: Okay. Can you explain how you got the value of $k=\frac{49}{16}$ with a little more detail?

Comment: I thought I explained. It says $\gt 148$ or $\lt 52$. But since (I assumed) a test score has to be an integer, $\gt 148$ means $\ge 149$, and $\lt 52$ means $\le 51$. If you look at the standard statement of the Chebyshev Inequality (see e.g. Wikipedia) you will see I think (did not check!) that it is exactly or essentially exactly as I stated it, with $\le$. So we really want $\Pr(|X-\mu|\ge 49)$.